# Access Host redis database from docker conatiner

Tags: python, database, docker, redis

I am trying to connect to host redis database through my docker conatiner.

In my dockerfile , I have redis as a requirement, which gets installed [pip install redis] and image is build using that docker file.
After than I instantiate the conatiner using following command

```
sudo docker run -p 6543:6543 your_image_name
```

my app.py is following

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.response import Response
import redis

def hello(request):
    ds_id = '4000'
    r_server = redis.Redis(unix_socket_path='/tmp/redis.sock')
    result = r_server.set('foo','11')
    return Response(result)
```

Problem is when Redis is installed in the beginning redis.sock file is not generated and thus creating error when I try to connect.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM     centos:latest

# load base packages w/ yum
RUN yum install -y git gcc libffi-devel openssl-devel python-devel postgresql-devel libxml2-devel libxslt-devel
COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py >get-pip.py && \
    python get-pip.py && \
    rm get-pip.py &&\
    pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 6543

WORKDIR /app

COPY app /app

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]

CMD [ "app.py" ]
```

requirements

```
pyramid
cornice
pyramid_chameleon
pyramid_beaker
pyramid_redis_sessions
pyRFC3339
oauthlib==0.7.2
oauth2client==1.5.2
pycrypto
PyOpenSSL
pymongo
SQLAlchemy
psycopg2
lxml
gspread
jira
waitress
paste
PasteDeploy
redis
```

Is there any other way to connect to host redis data.

Comment: Show us your Dockerfile. It seems that the redis server is not running yet.

Comment: I have added my docker file in the question

Comment: You have not installed the redis server and started it before running the python app. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31660691/1005215

Comment: /bin/sh: apt-get: command not found
I am not able to install redis-server using apt-get and I am doing this on centos 7. Any tips

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have a redis instance running on the host machine and just want the container to connect to that redis instance, then you just need to mount the socket file inside the container. For example, if the location of the socket file on the host machine is `/var/run/redis/redis.sock` and you want the location of the socket file inside the container to be `/tmp/redis.sock`, then launch the container like this:

   ```
   sudo docker run \
       -p 6543:6543 \
       -v  /var/run/redis/redis.sock:/tmp/redis.sock \
       your_image_name app.py
   ```
2. If you want to setup redis inside the container *and* run the python app, follow this:

   Create a file `start.sh` with the contents:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   /usr/bin/redis-server >/dev/null 2>&1 &
   /usr/bin/python $1
   ```

   Make the following modification to the file `app.py`:

   ```
   r_server = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
   ```

   Make the following modifications to your Dockerfile:

   Add the package `epel-release`

   ```
   RUN yum install -y git gcc libffi-devel openssl-devel python-devel postgresql-devel libxml2-devel libxslt-devel
   ```

   epel-release

   Install redis

   ```
   RUN yum install -y redis
   ```

   Copy the script created above to `/app` directory:

   ```
   COPY start.sh /app
   RUN chmod +x /app/start.sh
   ```

   Change entry point to start.sh

   ```
   ENTRYPOINT [ "/app/start.sh" ]
   ```

Comment: So I did the changes, created image and trying to run a docker container on port 6543. But when I go to localhost:6543 , it says unable to connect. I am using command  sudo docker run -p 6543:6543 image_name app.py

Comment: and when i check list of containers, i get Exited (0) 31 seconds ago status for my container @NehalJWani

Comment: I was actually passing app.py as a param when running docker container, using command  sudo docker run -p 6543:6543 image_name app.py. So now I have put that back to the place but still container is getting exited with status code 0

Comment: `from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.response import Response
import redis

def xyz(request):
    r_server = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
    result = r_server.set('label_name','11')
    return Response(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = Configurator()
    config.add_route('xyz', '/xyz')
    config.add_view(xyz, route_name='xyz')
    app = config.make_wsgi_app()
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 6543, app)
    server.serve_forever()`

Comment: Dockerfile is 
`EXPOSE 6543

WORKDIR /app

COPY app /app
RUN chmod +x /app/start.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "/app/start.sh" ]

CMD [ "app.py" ]`

Comment: start.sh is sitting in app folder so when i copy app folder, it also gets copied

Comment: Sorry, but AFAICs this is wrong, you do not pass on ports from the host to the container, its the other way arround. You cannot expose host-services using -p

Comment: @Ishita In the python script, I had written `$i` . I should have been `$1`. Check now.

Comment: getting this on console when I am running my container 
 `File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 442, in connect
    raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused.`

Comment: @Ishita I had changed how the redis server is spawned in start.sh. `/usr/bin/redis-server >/dev/null 2>&1 &`

Comment: still connection refused

Comment: @NehalJWani Also I was wonder will I be able to connect to redis using something as `redis.Redis(unix_socket_path='/tmp/redis.sock')`

Comment: @Ishita Do you have a redis instance running on the host machine?

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the hosts localhost loopback device, so what you do is https://gist.github.com/EugenMayer/3019516e5a3b3a01b6eac88190327e7c#file-gistfile1-txt

You create this file at

- `/Library/LaunchDaemons/docker.loopback.alias.plist`
- `sudo chown root:staff /Library/LaunchDaemons/docker.loopback.alias.plist`

you OSX. Then you restart your mac, after that, you can access the host loopback device using the ip `10.254.254.254` **from inside of the  container**, so from the container you can now configure redist to connect to `10.254.254.254:6543` - which will then use your osx-host redis

Theory:
You need to create this loopback alias, since you cannot use `localhost` in the container, since this would pick up the loopback device of the **container itself - his own loopback device** - not the loopback device of your host

Comment: If you are using a unixsocket, then no need to do all this. Just mount the socket file inside the container. See the first point in my answer.